# Office 365 word in outline view has started truncating long lines and adding at ellipsis, instead of wrapping around

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

This had been working ok.
Originally, I set this: 
Option  > Advanced > Show doc content > Show text wrapped within the doc window

And it worked ok.

A couple days ago, it stopped wrapping long lines, and just truncated them with an ellipsis

HERE IS THE PROBLEM:  ELIPSIS AND NO WRAP...
[image]

AND HERE'S OPTIONS ADVANCED...……………….
[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this ... what is your version and build number of Office 365 Word? Locate that under File > Account > About. Also please provide a screenshot.

Comment: Also check if the issue occurs in Draft view?

Comment: version and build added.  Does NOT occur in Draft view, which wraps around, just like I want, just like Outline view used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

PROBLEM:
Outlining tab > Show First Line Only … WAS CHECKED

SOLUTION:
Uncheck it.